# syslog shell expansion

Tags: linux, bash, shell, syslogd

Is there an easy way to prevent the logging of commands run into syslog as post-shell expansion ?

I.e log a command of "ls *.log" as just that, rather than "ls a.log b.log c.log d.log" It makes rather a mess of the log files.

Comment: Glob expansion is one of the first things the shell does. How are you doing the logging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure what you're trying to do but you can just do : `logger "ls *.log"`, maybe explain it better?

//edit how to redirect sudo output.

```
$ visudo 
# then set :
Defaults !syslog
Defaults logfile=/var/lot/sudo.log
```

Comment: Currently logging all commands run as root user. Some of the log lines are really long, where a user has performed a command with a shell expansion and it's been logged *after* that. e.g ls *.jpg in a directory with 2000 files, or such (as an example).

Comment: Aaah as with sudo, no that's not possible, however you can redirect the log to a different file that way your main log won't get polluted.

Comment: not always using sudo for the root user, logging in directly. I'll look into doing it for sudo though, thanks!

Comment: I'm 100% sure you can redirect the commands using syslogd's config file but I have never used it, I've been using rsyslog.